# не работает /dev/ttyUSB0 python

Tags: python

раньше работало сейчас нет вот код

```
def function():
  try:
    ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=0, xonxoff=False,rtscts=True, writeTimeout=None, dsrdtr=False, interCharTimeout=None)
  except:
    print("modem not conected")
    time.sleep(4)
    function()
function()
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, какую ОС вы используете, и что поменялось с прошлого раза, когда все работало

Comment: windows 11, когда работало и когда не работало. Я даже компютер не перезагружал с момента как оно работало и вот проблема

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите права доступа на файл /dev/ttyUSB0. Обычно у него группа uucp. Добавьте группу пользователю и перезайдите.

```
 adduser username uucp
```

А чтоб не ванговать, пишите исключение правильно.

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: а как дбавить группу в питоне?

Comment: не в питоне, а в системе

Comment: как это на винде сделать и есть ли
 какие то другие способы потому что я хочу выложить свою програму в общий доступ типа каждому сказать что вот добавте группу, все просто забют на мою прогу

Comment: на винде нет /dev/ttyUSB0 надо писать COM5 или типа того